# Prove or disprove that $\rho(A) = \| A \|_2$ for any real symmetric matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, symmetric-matrices, spectral-radius

I know that the spectral radius of a matrix is equal to the matrix's max absolute eigenvalue, and the equation to calculate the 2-norm of a matrix. But, I am not sure if those information are helpful to solve this problem.

Comment: The Euclidean norm is rotation invariant and a real symmetric $A$ can be diagonalised by an orthogonal transformation.

Comment: Would you give me more detailed information on how to prove it? I am not quite understand.

Comment: A real symmetric matrix $A$ can be written as $U \Lambda U^T$ where $\Lambda$ is a matrix of (real) eigenvalues and $U$ is orthogonal (that is, $U^TU = I$). The Euclidean norm satisfies $\|Ux\| = \|U\|$ for any orthogonal $U$.